# Variable appears as undefined in loop even though it is defined before the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

So, long story short, I'm trying to do a small script for a responsive slider and I'm trying to find the slide that has the most text so I know which one is the biggest slide. I then get the height of that slide and resize the slider container height to the height of the slide. I created a function that is ran on `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).resize()`. However, I'm having an issue with one of the variables.

The problem is this: As you can see, I define a variable called `lastlength` before I begin looping through the slides, I put its default value to zero. Then, I check if the `lastlength` of the previous slide is bigger than the `totallength` of the current slide, if it is not bigger, I change the value of `lastlength` to the value of `totallength`.

However, I noticed that the conditional statements weren't returning anything at all, so when I did a `console.log(lastlength)` I noticed that the variable appeared as undefined although I defined it before the loop. I tried making sure the name was right by copying the argument I provided to `console.log` and replacing the name of the variable for that.

Here's the function:

```
function changeSlider(numslides)
{
    var id_current = 1;
    var lastlength = 0;
    var lastlength_owner = 0;
    $(".slide").each(function()
    {
        var texth2 = $(this).children("h1").text();
        var texth3 = $(this).children("h3").text();

        var totallength = texth2.length + texth3.length;

        console.log(lastlength);
        console.log(totallength);

        if ( (lastlength > totallength) && (id_current == numslides) )
        {
            console.log(totallength);
            changeSize(lastlength_owner);
        }

        if ( (lastlength < totallength) && (id_current == numslides) )
        {
            console.log(totallength);
            $(".slider").css('height', $(this).height());
        }

        if ( (lastlength < totallength) && (id_current !== numslides) )
        {
            console.log(totallength);
            var lastlength = totallength;
            var lastlength_owner = $(this).attr('slide_id');
        }

        id_current++;
    }); 
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you redeclare `lastlength` and `lastlength_owner` later on:

```
var lastlength = totallength;
var lastlength_owner = $(this).attr('slide_id');
```

These declarations shadow the `var` variables outside the function.

Just remove the `var` keywords here and it should work.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I was not aware that I had put the var keyword before  changing the value of the variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You redefine it at

```
var lastlength = totallength;
```

And because of variable hoisting, this causes the function to effectively begin with

```
var lastlength;
```

Just get rid of the `var`.